# Add 'end' automatically in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I have been looking for a way for atom to automatically add an 'end' when needed, such as when I define a method.

Does anyone know if this is possible at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anyone yet, but it may worth to you being alert on this post: https://github.com/atom/bracket-matcher/issues/7